# How to compare subpopulations? stdev?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, standard-deviation

I want to see if the average of Group A is significantly more than Groups B and C. I'd like a continuous measure of this significance.

Then I'd like to compare B to CA, and C to BA.

```
Population {
    Subpopulation A { avg: 4.90, count: 23 }
    Subpopulation B { avg: 4.10, count: 67 }
    Subpopulation C { avg: 0.00, count: 12 } 
}
```

Should I compare:

- A's mean to the 'stdev of the weighted avg of B and C'?
- A's mean to the 'weighted average of the entire population.'?
- Or should I really be comparing A to B and C separately?

---

EDIT: this ANOVA looks promising

[image]

Comment: None of the above, because the tests are interrelated.  You should be conducting a preliminary test to see whether there are any differences at all.  This is usually done with an Analysis of Variance or the equivalent.  "ANOVA" is a good search term.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.f_oneway.html

Comment: Yes, that's the right idea.  There are issues with the follow-up tests to see which is largest.  An attractive solution is Tukey's HSD.

Comment: holy cow there are a lot of these multiple comparison, post hoc tests
https://www.statisticshowto.datasciencecentral.com/post-hoc/

Comment: Now I wonder if i will be able to achieve significance/ converge w 10 samples in each group

Comment: That depends on how large the population effect sizes are - how many standard deviations the group means are from the overall mean. At small sample sizes you need large effects to have a good chance to detect them.